# Show that the series diverges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges conditionally. Show that the series $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}n(\log n)(\log\log n)^{2} a_{n}$ is divergent. I tried this question with summation by parts but no conclusion. Can anyone give some hint?

Comment: What would $n(\log n)(\log \log n)^2a_n \to 0$ imply for $\sum a_n$?

Comment: Do you mean by contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

Let series $\sum n(\log n)(\log(\log n))^2a_n$ be convergent. Then, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} n(\log n)(\log(\log n))^2a_n=0$ implying $$\lim_{n\to\infty} n(\log n)(\log(\log n))^2|a_n|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_n|}{\frac{1}{n(\log n)(\log(\log n))^2}}=0.$$ This implies that series $\sum |a_n|$ is convergent by limit comparison test and by the convergence of the series $$\sum \frac{1}{n(\log n)(\log (\log n))^2},$$ which contradicts with conditional convergence of $\sum a_n$. Hence, series $\sum n(\log n)(\log(\log n))^2a_n$ is divergent.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sum a_n$ converges conditionally,
then $\sum |a_n|$ diverges.

Let $b_n$ be any positive sequence such that
$\sum \dfrac1{b_n}
$
converges.

Claim:
$\sum b_n a_n
$
diverges.

Proof.
(modeled after guest's answer)

If
$\sum b_n a_n
$
converges,
then
$b_n a_n \to 0$,
so that
$b_n |a_n| \to 0$,
or
$\dfrac{|a_n|}{\dfrac1{b_n}}
\to
0
$.
Therefore,
since
$\sum \dfrac1{b_n}
$
converges,
$\sum |a_n|$
also converges,
which contradicts the
conditional convergence
of $\sum a_n
$.